How can I prevent repetitions of plain object types in function signatures?
Context
I am building a generic querying library. It can take a 'Schema', and can return a mapped output type, based on what you query.
A simplified example looks like this:
type QueryResponse<S extends object, O extends object> = {
  [K in keyof O]: K extends keyof S
  ? S[K]
  : never
}

function makeQuery<S extends Schema>() {
  return function query<O extends object>(q: O): QueryResponse<S, O> {
    return {} as QueryResponse<S, O>
  }
}

interface Schema {
  post: { title: string; content: string }
  author: { title: string; content: string }
}
const query = makeQuery<Schema>();
             // <-- hover over here
const res = query({ post: {}, author: {} })
res.post.title // types as a string
res.author.title // types as a string

Playground Link
Problem
If you hover over res = query, the intellisense can start to look inscrutable:
const query: <{
    post: {};
    author: {};
}>(q: {
    post: {};
    author: {};
}) => QueryResponse<Schema, {
    post: {};
    author: {};
}>

Goal
I would love it if the intellisense for query was more readble.
Maybe if the user could provide the type name for example:
const query: <PostAuthorQuery>(q: PostAuthorQuery) => QueryResponse<Schema, PostAuthorQuery>

Problem
There's no idiomatic way I know of for a user to create PostAuthorQuery from an object. So far, I know they could do this:
const _query = { post: {}, author: {} };
type _PostAuthorQuery = typeof _query;
interface PostAuthorQuery extends _PostAuthorQuery {};
const query: PostAuthorQuery = _query;

But I can't really ask them to write this boilerplate for each query.
Question
Is there some helper I could create for a user, so when they generate queries, and use my query function, they see a more concise intellisense definition?
Or maybe I could approach the problem differently? Perhaps if I used a different input (i.e not an object), the intellisense would look nicer? I tried a builder pattern but the intellisense did not look so nice.

Uhhh so this seems like the last question except now you’re no longer happy with the solution.  I mean the type needs to show up multiple times. Why does it matter how it looks when you hover over query anyway? I’m not sure why you’d want to fight against the TS type display so much. ‍♂️

I actually am happy with the previous question @jcalz! (That solved the problem of Schema expanding everywhere). Now I'm trying to tackle a more dynamic part, where the user can define different queries, and I don't really have much control over that.
My hope is that by reducing the verbosity in the intellisense, when there's an error the user can see it more clearly. I don't have a lot of deep TS experience, so I sometimes wonder if I restructure the code in some way, if it will conform to a more idiomatic style, and produce a better API for users

I don't see anything non-idiomatic about IntelliSense showing type arguments when you call a generic fn. Pragmatically speaking any useful type argument is going to show up at least three times in a function call, since it needs to be declared, and needs to be mentioned in the input somewhere, and then one other place (or else you might not need the generic at all). I don't see anything wrong with the IntelliSense here, so I'm not even sure there's anything to do. Right now it sounds like you're asking for the impossible, or maybe I'm just not understanding. Could you [edit] to clarify?

Thanks for taking the time @jcalz, I edited the question to clarify my goal a bit more. Does it make more sense? It may just be that I am asking for the impossible, in which case I can stick with the current interface

"I can't really ask them to write this boilerplate for each query" That boilerplate doesn't make sense to me (what is _q? Why aren't you calling query there? Why wouldn't you just write the interface to start with?) But to some extent users of TS know that they either have to write interfaces or they have to see anonymous object types. There's no third option that I know of. Still not sure how to proceed here.

Gotcha, it does sound like I am asking for the impossible. I was hoping for some way to define both the interface and the object in one go (This would be particularly useful here, since both the interface and the object are would look very similar). However, I can see this just isn't possible at the moment. If you like, feel free to answer with a 'this is just expected behavior', and will accept it ).

As discussed in the comments, the only way to get around this, is to either a) explicitly define the type:
type PostAuthorQuery: { post: {}, object: { } }
const query: PostAuthorQuery = { post: { }, object: { } }

Or, to avoid writing the same object twice, you could use the interface trick:
const _query = { post: {}, author: {} };
type _PostAuthorQuery = typeof _query;
interface PostAuthorQuery extends _PostAuthorQuery {};
const query: PostAuthorQuery = _query;

